# Editing validation summary using c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, validation, customvalidator

I want to create a custom validation summary so that I can edit the default rendering of asp:ValidationSummary with links  to the specific error fields (somewhat like WET).

**my Custom Class:**

```
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Security;
    using System.Security.Permissions;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    [assembly: TagPrefix("Web.Boew", "wet")]
     namespace Wet.Boew
      {

    [
        ToolboxData("<{0}:CustomValidationSummary CssClass='label label-danger' ID='ValidationSummary' runat=\"server\"></{0}:CustomValidationSummary>")
    ]
    public class CustomValidationSummary : System.Web.UI.WebControls.ValidationSummary
    {
        [
            Browsable(true),
            Category("Appearance"),
            DefaultValue(""),
            Description("Validation Summary.")
        ]

        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "label label-danger");
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div);
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Ul);
            // Call the base class's Render method.
            base.Render(writer);

            foreach (BaseValidator v in Page.Validators)
            {
                //base.Render(writer);

                var o = v.FindControl(v.ControlToValidate);
                if (o != null && v.ValidationGroup.Equals(this.ValidationGroup))
                {
                    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Li);
                    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href, "#" + o.ClientID);
                    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.A);
                    writer.Write(o.ToString());
                    writer.RenderEndTag();
                    writer.RenderEndTag();
                }
            }
            writer.RenderEndTag();
            writer.RenderEndTag();

        }
    }
}
```

**Tag:**

```
    <wet:CustomValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary2" runat="server"  
      ValidationGroup="Registration" HeaderText="Following errors occured:" />
```

**Rendered HTML:**
[image]

**What is happening:**
if you see the image above. When the page is loaded it gets pre-loaded with list of `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox` which is clickable to textfield. which is correct. But when I press submit I see the errors list above as generated by `base.Render(writer)`.

**What I want:**

I want to edit the list generated by `base.Render(writer)`. and edit its HTML to include links to the text fields which have errors. if any one can help sorry I am new to asp and C#.

Final Output I Desire:
[image]

Comment: is there any reason to link the _errors_ ?

Comment: Client's specification. So that people with disabilities can easily focus on the fields giving error. As part of the Web experience Toolkit initiative.
[link](https://wet-boew.github.io/v4.0-ci/demos/formvalid/formvalid-en.html)